# How does convox exec <pid> "cat - > file.txt" < file.txt work?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to understand this shell cmd.

I understand that:

`convox exec <pid>` is going to execute the following cmd in the container with pid as the ID

`< file.txt work` redirects the content of file.txt file as input to the convox cmd

`> file.txt` overwrite the file context with whatever is on the left of that > redirect operator

Then the question is what does that `cat -` do? How does the content of my local file.txt get passed to the command that is going to run within the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cat - > file.txt` command is executed *inside* the container, while the `< file.txt`, which is outside of the quotes ("..."), affects the `convox exec` command itself.

In other words, this redirects stdin for the `convox exec` command from `stdin`, and then `cat - > file.txt` reads from stdin and writes to the file `file.txt` inside the container.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I never seen the `cat -` syntax, is that part of shell or convox cmd? could you give me a link to some reference? I try to google it but didn't get anything.

Comment: `cat` is a standard unix command that reads one or more files and writes them to `stdout`.  `-` is a special argument that means `stdin`.  `cat` reads from stdin by default, so `cat - > file.txt` is equivalent to `cat > file.txt`.